# Solve this three dimensional ODE by using Decoupled method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{align}\frac{dx}{dt}&= x-y-z\\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&= x+y\\\
\frac{dz}{dt}&= 3x+z\end{align}$$

I tried to solve this by using complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

But would decouple method be easy?

Comment: You will get that $Y=(\exp(t),\exp((1-2i)t),\exp((1+2i)t))^{T}$. Multiplying this vector by the matrix $P$ tells you the vector $X$ and this the solution $x,y,z$ of the original system.

Comment: Thanks, Is P the Eigen vectors of A? And what is Matrix J here

Comment: Yes, $P$'s columns are the coordinates of the eigenvectors of $A$ in the usual basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The matrix $J$ is $D$. I mixed up the names.